# Create sequential counting in data frame column

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame looking like this:

```
Value1   Value2
1        543
1        845
3        435
5        724
5        234
8        204
```

Now, I would like the first column to count up sequentially, instead of jumping several steps every time the value changes, like so:

```
Value1   Value2
1        543
1        845
2        435
3        724
3        234
4        204
```

If there was some way of simply replacing an element in a data frame with something else, this could be easily done. However, I don't know if there is such a command. Also, I guess some kind of macro command for doing something like this would do, but I guess there isn't such a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the fact that `factor` levels will be increasing integers:

```
> x <- c(1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 8)
> as.numeric(factor(x))
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
```

Comment: You could also do explcity what those commands do implicitly: use match, sort and unique

Comment: With the addition of @Dirk Eddelbuettel's code from his comment on his answer, this is the method I used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with indexing. In essence, you want to add one each time the value in the column changes.

Define the data:

```
R> z <- c(1,1,3,5,5,8)
```

All-but-last and all-but-first:

```
R> head(z,-1)
[1] 1 1 3 5 5
R> z[-1] 
[1] 1 3 5 5 8
```

Compare, invert comparison and then sum over booleans:

```
R> z[-1] == head(z,-1)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
R> z[-1] != head(z,-1)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
R> cumsum(z[-1] != head(z,-1))
[1] 0 1 2 2 3
R>
```

And then use this where we add 1 to make up for the initial pair-wise comparison:

```
R> cumsum(c(1, z[-1] != head(z,-1)))
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
```

So you could use such an expression to replace the value in your `data.frame`.

Comment: Nice, but I guess what I'm really after is how to implement these numbers into my data frame. That is, for example, if I want to replace the value of the third row, second column, how do I do that?

Comment: You replace entire columns of the data.frame at once. In your notation, and assuming your `data.frame` is called `x` (as you never said as your example was not reproducible):  `x[,"Value1"] <- cumsum(c(1, x[-1,"Value2"] != head(x[,"Value2"], -1)))`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm now, although @Andrie's solution was enough for my particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I kind of like @Andrie's solution. But the first thing I thought of was to use `rle`:

```
x <- c(1,1,3,5,5,8)
r <- rle(x)

> rep(seq_len(length(r$lengths)),times = r$lengths)
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
```

One nice thing about @Andrie's solution is that it doesn't assume your vector is sorted, I believe, whereas this (and @Dirk's I believe) both assume it's been sorted.